# Is there any reason for Google App Engine behaviour is different between local dev environment and cloud?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jersey, jackson

I encounter a problem when I deploy Jersey app on Google App Engine. The behaviour is different between the local and cloud. The detail is that:

I add a CustomMapperProvider for Jersey.

```
@Override
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {

    Set<Class<?>> resources = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
    resources.add(CustomMapperProvider.class);
    return resources;
}
```

And the CustomMapperProvider is as follows:

```
public class CustomMapperProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

@Override
public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
    /** Generate Default mapper*/
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addDeserializer(User.class, new UserDeserializer());
    module.addSerializer(User.class, new UserSerializer());
    mapper.registerModule(module);
    return mapper;
    }
}
```

This CustomeMapperProvider is for custom generation for the User Class JSON.

The problem is that, I test the app in local dev environment, and the UserSerializer is work for the JSON generation. But I deployed it on the cloud, the result is different, and according to the result, I know that the JSON is not generated by the custom JSON serializer.

So is there any restriction or any different between Google App Engine in cloud and local dev environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The different behaviour I have encountered are as follows:

1. The GAE has some limitations
2. The datastore maybe has different data

So, just make more log and check it in GAE console

Answer (score 0):

You should provide samples showing difference here.
Without samples I assume your local box is windows and GAE is linux vm. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Nope, my local dev environment is Fedora 24. Let me make a small demo later to reproduce the issue.